# Need help rounding Mysql results that are returned from a python function

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I am relatively new to python and I am working on creating a program in my fun time to automatically generate a sales sheet. It has several functions that pull the necessary data from a database, and reportlab and a few other tools to place the results onto the generated pdf. I am trying to round the results coming from the Mysql server. However, I have hit a point where I am stuck and all the ways I have tried to round the results throw an error code and do not work. I need a few examples to look at so I can see how this would work and any relevant feedback that would help me learn.

I have tried to use the mysql round function to round the results but that failed. I have also tried to round the results as part of the function that generates the unit cost itself. However, that has failed as well.

A large amount of the code has been deleted due to the security hole it would generate. Code provided is to show what I have done so far. Print result line is to verify that the code is working during development. It is not throwing any erroneous results and will be removed during the last stage of the project.

```
 def upcpsfunc(self, upc):
    mycursor = self.mydb.cursor()
    command = "Select Packsize from name"" where UPC = %(Upc)s"
    mycursor.execute(command, {'Upc': upc})
    result = mycursor.fetchone()
    print(result[0])
    return result[0]

 def unitcost(self,upc):
    #function to generate unit cost
    mycursor = self.mydb.cursor()
    command = "Select Concat((Cost - Allow)/Packsize) as total from name 
    where UPC = %(Upc)s"
    mycursor.execute(command, {'Upc': upc})
    result = mycursor.fetchone()
    print (result[0])
    return result[0]
```

As for the expected results, I would prefer the mysql command round the results before it sends it to Reportlab for placement. So far the results are 4 or 5 digits, which is not ideal. I want the results to have two decimal places, since it would be money. The desired output is 7.50 instead 7.5025

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `round` function can be used to round numbers:

```
>>> round(7.5025, 2)
7.5
```

To get the extra 0 on the end, you can use the following code:

```
>>> def round_money(n):
    s = str(round(n, 2))
    if len(s) == 1: # exact dollar
        return s + ".00"
    elif len(s) == 3: # exact x10 cents
        return s + "0"
    return s

>>> round_money(6)
'6.00'
>>> round_money(7.5025)
'7.50'
```

Note that this function returns a string, because `7.50` cannot be represented by an integer in python.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an alternative way to the one already provided, you can do the same thing with string formatting (it'll truncate the decimals though, so you can still round beforehand):

```
>>> '{:,.2f}'.format(0)
'0.00'
>>> '{:,.2f}'.format(15342.62412)
'15,342.62'
```